# Ranking student grades based on 3 fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to assign new roll no (ranking student) based on 3 fields. My data and expected results looks like below. Here is google drive link to [download sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/118np0DJA8POeiArlwtsaXgcfz0zuMRyv/view?usp=sharing) file. Logics are explained below to rank the students.

| AutoID | roll | name | total | gpa | grade | failcount | ResultExpected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Name1 | 531 | 3.38 | B | 0 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | Name2 | 530 | 3.37 | D | 0 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 | Name3 | 520 | 3.38 | B | 0 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | Name4 | 351 | 2 | c | 0 | 5 |
| 5 | 5 | Name5 | 560 | 3.59 | A- | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 6 | Name6 | 110 | 0 | F | 4 | 7 |
| 7 | 7 | Name7 | 71 | 0 | F | 2 | 6 |
| 8 | 8 | Name8 | 102 | 0 | F | 4 | 8 |
| 9 | 9 | Name9 | 88 | 0 | F | 7 | 10 |
| 10 | 10 | Name10 | 25 | 0 | F | 5 | 9 |

- First consider `failcount`. The students who do not fail in any subject he will be first ranking based on their GPA (Grade Point Average). Lower `FailCount` with higher `GPA` will rank first. Here `roll 5` has higher GPA while he do not fail in any subject.
- After considering `failcount` if `GPA` is same then `total` will be compared and higher `total` with same `GPA` will rank first. Here `roll 1` and `roll 3` has same GPA but `roll 1` has higher `total` so, `roll 1` will rank first between these two student.
- Same logic will be applied for same `failcount` with higher `total`.

By following query I can rank student based on 2 fields `gpa` & `total` but can't figure out `failcount`.

```
SELECT rnk.*, IIf(rnk.GPA>0,(select count(*)
        from [tblResults] as rnk2
        where rnk2.gpa >0 AND
              (rnk2.gpa > rnk.gpa or
               rnk2.gpa = rnk.gpa and rnk2.total >= rnk.total
              )
       ),0) AS ranking
FROM tblResults AS rnk;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have been here long enough to know that all information needed to analyze an issue should be included in question, not in a download file. And that data sample should be text table, not image, or code snippet that builds table. I worked with another question where OP posted snippet to build table and I was able to copy/paste data to Access table. Help us help you.

Comment: So Name3 places higher than Name2 because of higher GPA even though Name2 has higher total?

Comment: @June7 Sorry for my mistake, updated. You are correct in second comment.

Comment: Shouldn't there be some records where student has a failcount >0 but not F grade? I gave Name4 a failcount of 2 and in @Applecore query it gets same rank as Name7 - both are 5 and there is no rank 6. Access doesn't handle ranking well. Other db like SQLServer have functions that could probably easily do this.

Comment: Since plain old sort seems to put records in correct order, an alternative is to build a report, apply sort criteria to its design and use textbox RunningSum property to calculate 'rank'. However, nothing in your data shows tied records. RunningSum will not show tied records with same rank. Surely in a large dataset there will be ties?

Comment: If a student has Failcount>0 but not grade F, as @June7 says, then I think that your original query would need to be changed to use `Failcount` in the `IIf` statement.

Comment: More about ranking/numbering in Access http://allenbrowne.com/ranking.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS Access, you can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select r.*,
       (select count(*)
        from tblResults as r2
        where r2.failcount < r.failcount or
              (r2.failcount = r.failcount and r2.gpa > r.gpa) or
              (r2.failcount = r.failcount and r2.gpa = r.gpa and r2.total >= r.total)
       ) as result_expected
from tblResults as r
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that one way of doing this is to use a `UNION` query to deal with the two parts separately. Something like this gives the expected results:

```
SELECT rnk.*, 
    (select count(*) from tblResults as rnk2 where rnk2.gpa>0 and (rnk2.gpa>rnk.gpa or rnk2.gpa=rnk.gpa and rnk2.total>=rnk.total)) as ranking
FROM tblResults AS rnk
WHERE rnk.failcount=0
UNION SELECT rnk.*,
    (select count(*) from tblresults as rnk2 where (rnk2.failcount<rnk.failcount and rnk2.failcount>0) or (rnk2.failcount=rnk.failcount and rnk2.total>rnk.total and rnk2.failcount>0)) 
    +(select count(*) from tblresults as rnk2 where rnk2.failcount=0)+1
from tblresults as rnk
where failcount>0
```

Regards,

Comment: Your solution gives duplicate ranking when failcount is same. I have tried with failcount 2,2,2 for 3 students and it gives ranking for those 3 students although their total is different.

Comment: Sorry - my mistake. There was a typo in the `WHERE` clause that was greater than 2, rather than greater than 0. Fixed, and also removed the original `IIf` statement as that is superfluous.

Comment: Now it is working fine! Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my RecordNumber function found here [VBA.RowNumbers](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.RowNumbers):

```vb
' Creates and returns a sequential record number for records displayed
' in a form, even if no primary or unique key is present.
' For a new record, Null is returned until the record is saved.
'
' Implementation, typical:
'
'   Create a TextBox to display the record number.
'   Set the ControlSource of this to:
'
'       =RecordNumber([Form])
'
'   The returned number will equal the Current Record displayed in the
'   form's record navigator (bottom-left).
'   Optionally, specify another first number than 1, say, 0:
'
'       =RecordNumber([Form],0)
'
'   NB: For localised versions of Access, when entering the expression, type
'
'       =RecordNumber([LocalisedNameOfObjectForm])
'
'   for example:
'
'       =RecordNumber([Formular])
'
'   and press Enter. The expression will update to:
'
'       =RecordNumber([Form])
'
'   If the form can delete records, insert this code line in the
'   AfterDelConfirm event:
'
'       Private Sub Form_AfterDelConfirm(Status As Integer)
'           Me!RecordNumber.Requery
'       End Sub
'
'   If the form can add records, insert this code line in the
'   AfterInsert event:
'
'       Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
'           Me!RecordNumber.Requery
'       End Sub
'
' Implementation, stand-alone:
'
'   Dim Number As Variant
'
'   Number = RecordNumber(Forms(IndexOfFormInFormsCollection))
'   ' or
'   Number = RecordNumber(Forms("NameOfSomeOpenForm"))
'
'
' 2018-09-14. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function RecordNumber( _
    ByRef Form As Access.Form, _
    Optional ByVal FirstNumber As Long = 1) _
    As Variant

    ' Error code for "There is no current record."
    Const NoCurrentRecord   As Long = 3021
    
    Dim Records             As DAO.Recordset
    
    Dim Number              As Variant
    Dim Prompt              As String
    Dim Buttons             As VbMsgBoxStyle
    Dim Title               As String

    On Error GoTo Err_RecordNumber
    If Form Is Nothing Then
        ' No form object is passed.
        Number = Null
    ElseIf Form.Dirty = True Then
        ' No record number until the record is saved.
        Number = Null
    ElseIf Form.NewRecord = True Then
        ' No record number on a new record.
        Number = Null
    Else
        Set Records = Form.RecordsetClone
        Records.Bookmark = Form.Bookmark
        Number = FirstNumber + Records.AbsolutePosition
        Set Records = Nothing
    End If
    
Exit_RecordNumber:
    RecordNumber = Number
    Exit Function
    
Err_RecordNumber:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case NoCurrentRecord
            ' Form is at new record, thus no Bookmark exists.
            ' Ignore and continue.
        Case Else
            ' Unexpected error.
            Prompt = "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
            Buttons = vbCritical + vbOKOnly
            Title = Form.Name
            MsgBox Prompt, Buttons, Title
    End Select
    
    ' Return Null for any error.
    Number = Null
    Resume Exit_RecordNumber

End Function
```

Create a query to sort as to your specification:

```sql
SELECT 
    tblResults.AutoID, 
    tblResults.roll, 
    tblResults.name, 
    tblResults.total, 
    tblResults.gpa, 
    tblResults.grade, 
    tblResults.failcount
FROM 
    tblResults
ORDER BY 
    tblResults.failcount, 
    tblResults.gpa DESC, 
    tblResults.total DESC;
```

Now, use that as source in a form where you add one more textbox having this ControlSource:

```
=RecordNumber([Form])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Gustav, your `RecordNumber()` function works. Can we use it to report so that we can print in our expected format?

Comment: No. The function takes a _Form_ argument. In a report, it is much easier; _move_ the sorting from the query to the report, then have a textbox having the value of 1 and set it up as _running sum_.

Comment: Oh thats it. `Running Sum` is good option. Thanks.